# How to get a JS cookie that was created without page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have this service that creates a cookie without doing any page load. So the cookie gets created however my function to retrieve that cookie runs with the first page load and fails, given that cookie has not been created yet. Is there anyway I can listen to the cookie creation (which is created without loading the page) before firing my function?

This is what I have so far:

```
function customerExists() {

     var customer-id  =  Cookies.get('customer-id')

       if ($('.customer-text')[0] && customer-id == '39494' ) {

         $(".customer-mesg").show(); 

      } else {
       $(".customer-mesg").hide();
      }
}
```

Comment: The issue is the service that creates the cookie is a third party service so I cannot really manipulate that or access its code.

Comment: Cookies cannot be set without there being an HTTP request being made and a response handled by the browser. You should know about that request and be able to read the cookie after it is made.

Comment: How a cookie is created without loading a page? A client-side cookie is created by the page (or the javascript called in a page). Is it a server side cookie?

Comment: It is just a cookie that is created by a react app without loading the page. Pretty much if I do if cookie exists, then I would always get false even after its creation.

Comment: I mean, you can set up a timer and check for the cookie every second or something like that... It would be better if the React app could broadcast a message that you could -- pun intended -- react to.

Comment: I tried the timer and it works, but is it good practice to run a function every 1 second?

Comment: if you kill it when it ran it shouldn't make any difference. Be sure to comment sufficiently for your co. devs to understand

Comment: Well  I cannot kill it as I am not sure when would the user provide their input which gets stores in a cookie.

Comment: did you run a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` ? because an interval you have to kill since it will run every second and a timeout is fine but prone to error. Learn to deal with asynchronous stuff with callbacks and Promises.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, write a function that returns a `Promise` that resolves to the cookie. Then just use `.then(res=>funcAfterCookie(res))` on the function call to create the cookie or on the `Promise` object itself.

Comment: Well, that's the trick, isn't it? How does one "write a function that returns a Promise that resolves to the cookie"?

Comment: where is the cookie created? just return a promise that resolves to the cookie

Comment: How would I know? You're the one with the answer! :) (I'm not the OP)

Comment: and as long the question doesn't specify this. I can only give a general answer. He wants to wait for something --> use a Promise

Comment: Yes I said wait for the cookie to be created, not something!